# jquery tooltip on ModalPopupExtender incorrect position

Tags: jquery, tooltip, modalpopupextender

Here is the tooltip I am using right now:

```
$('.popupMsg').hover(function (event) {
                var msg = parseInt($(this).attr('Tooltip'));
                $('<div class="tooltipx">' + msg + '</div>')
                    .appendTo('.remarkPopupX')
                    .css('top', (event.pageY - 10) + 'px')
                    .css('left', (event.pageX + 10) + 'px')
                      .fadeIn(0);
            }, function () {
                $('.tooltipx').remove();

            }).mousemove(function (event) {
                var q = GetScreenCoordinates(event.target);
                $('.tooltipx')

                .css('top', (event.pageY - 10) + 'px')
                .css('left', (event.pageX + 10) + 'px')


            });
```

and the css:

```
.tooltipx {
            display: none;
            font-family: Tahoma; 
            position: absolute;
            border: 2px solid #000000;
            background-color: #FFFFAA;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            color:  #000000;
            text-align: left;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```

On the parent page, I have no problem whatsoever with this custom tooltip(either in maximum windows or default size).  However, the tooltip acts strangely different on the ModalExtenderPopup.  It appears away from the target element(almost outside of the modalpopup);  If I change the window size, its position changes to somewhere else.  It looks like somehow its content width and height is affected by the modalpopup itself.  So how to get this tooltip display at correct position (next to the target element) on modalpopupextender?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well i cant tell the exact solution.I was working on same for tooltip and was having this position problem and i tried to show the tooltip first then positioned it with a blink , it worked for me.Try it like that for testing .This might give you some clue.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by getting the container (panel) coordinate(top, left offset) before showing the modalpopup.  Then substract these offests to the event.pageX and event.pageY respectively.